# Politeness particles `krap`/`ka`

Tags: thai

What is the original meaning of `krap`/`ka` politeness particles and what are their equivalents in Indo-European languages?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Thai wiktionary](https://th.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B8%B1%E0%B8%9A) ขอรับ *kráp* is a shortening of ขอรับ *kɔ̌ɔ-ráp* "ask to serve" = "may I serve you?".  *Ká*, however, is uncertain.

I don't think there's a single equivalent to these politeness markers in IE languages, where politeness and gender are marked by different mechanisms.